# Prevent Automapper from returning non-empty list for empty source

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I have automapper set up like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<FieldEntry, FieldEntryModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.DestOptions,
        source => source.MapFrom(f => f.Field.Options));

Mapper.CreateMap<FieldOption, string>()
    .ConvertUsing(o => o.Name);
```

However, when I call this on data for which no options exist, instead of returning an empty `DestOptions` list, it returns a `DestOptions` list with a single `null` entry.

In other words, `DestOptions.length = 1, DestOptions[0] = null`.

In case it matters, I'm calling it from an EF query `ProjectTo`, i.e.:

```
var result = db.FieldEntries.ProjectTo<FieldEntryModel>().ToList();
```

**Edit**: to make it more explicit, running:

```
db.FieldEntries.Include(f => f.Field.Options).FirstOrDefault().Field.Options.Count
```

returns zero.

Comment: what is the length of your source object?

Comment: Use something like `source => source.MapFrom(f => f.Field.Options, opts => opts.PreCondition((src) => src.Field.Options != null && src.Field.Options.Any()));`

Comment: @Simonare: the length is zero: there are no options on the source object. In fact, the Options table is completely empty.

Comment: @NaDeRStar: I just tried adding a precondition and it did not change the outcome.

Comment: Check [the execution plan](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Understanding-your-mapping.html).

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu, the execution plan doesn't show any surprises. It looks exactly like the mapping, translated into LINQ.

Comment: Really? :) But you seem to be saying that somehow AM is manufacturing a list with one element from an empty list.

Comment: Maybe all you're seeing is an outer join.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu, yes, it's stumping me too. :) I'm going to try to create a minimal example that you guys can run yourselves.

Comment: I wasn't able to easily pare this down to an example, but I did confirm that it's because ProjectTo is constructing an outer join in its EF query. For now I worked around it by just checking for that case after the query returns, since none of my Options should be null in the first place.